# Access Chrome Enterprise AssetID in PWA

Tags: google-chrome, vue.js, google-chrome-app

As of Chrome 81, Google [allows managed Chrome Devices to add a PWA in Kiosk Mode](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9781496?hl=en).

There's not a lot of documentation around this, but I've got it working in a basic fashion. I'd like to get the device asset ID, conceivably through `chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceAssetId(function callback)` as found [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes).

I've added the `enterprise.deviceAttributes` permission to the PWA manifest, but I'm not sure that's relevant here.  I'm trying to access this asset ID through a Vue frontend:

```
assetID () {
 if (chrome.enterprise) {
   chrome.enterprise.deviceAttributes.getDeviceAssetId(deviceId => {
     return deviceId
   })
 } else {
   return 'Not a Chrome Device'
 }
},
```

This is my latest attempt at it, but I can't even seem to verify that the `chrome.enterprise` api is available. Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

From the Chrome OS developer docs https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/enterprise_deviceAttributes

> Note: This API is only available to extensions force-installed by
>   enterprise policy.

You will need to build a chrome app or extension to use the enterprise APIs and then pass the info to your PWA https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app

Comment: Chrome App support wil end in juni 2022 and are deprecated in 2020. So that wont be a solution any more.